# Type error: Argument 1 passed to Collective\Html\FormBuilder::open() must be of the type array, object given

Tags: php, laravel-5

i'm getting trouble with form collective in laravel and here is my form

```
{!! Form::open($histories,['route' => ['campaign.admin.storeHistory',$histories->campaign_id] , ['id'=>'project-form','method'=>'POST']]) !!}
        @include('campaign.admin.form',['title' => 'Thêm mới ủng hộ','submit' => 'Thêm mới'])
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

and error is Type error: Argument 1 passed to Collective\Html\FormBuilder::open() must be of the type array, object given. help me thanks!

Comment: please post how you are getting the $histories variable

Comment: here is my controller

Comment: public function createHistory($id){
        $histories = History::where('campaign_id',$id);
        return view('campaign.admin.addHistory', compact('histories'));
    }

Comment: History::where('campaign_id',$id)->toArray(); and try again

Comment: error again bro :( Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::toArray()

Comment: oops History::where('campaign_id',$id)->get()->toArray(); try this bro

Comment: yeah, i did that but error Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\OpenServer\domains\kindmate\resources\views\campaign\admin\addHistory.blade.php)

Comment: i think i wrong params in form model :(

Comment: ok so after doing that you need to change your blade form to this $histories['campaign_id']